# how to extract data from JSON when JSON object is name is not atomic

Tags: javascript

The following is a simple JSON object created using Xstream. Is it a valid JavaScript object. Actualy I want to ask how to access first persons information like id ,username, password etc.But when I view this file in browser the displayed webpage is not showing "21". I expect that page should display 21.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script>
        var obj = {"records":[
                     {"beans.Person":[
                        {"id":21,"name":"Name21","username":"Username21","password":"password21","age":41,"sex":true},
                        {"id":22,"name":"Name22","username":"Username22","password":"password22","age":42,"sex":true},
                        {"id":23,"name":"Name23","username":"Username23","password":"password23","age":43,"sex":true},
                        {"id":24,"name":"Name24","username":"Username24","password":"password24","age":44,"sex":true},
                        {"id":25,"name":"Name25","username":"Username25","password":"password25","age":45,"sex":true},
                        {"id":26,"name":"Name26","username":"Username26","password":"password26","age":46,"sex":true},
                        {"id":27,"name":"Name27","username":"Username27","password":"password27","age":47,"sex":true},
                        {"id":28,"name":"Name28","username":"Username28","password":"password28","age":48,"sex":true},
                        {"id":29,"name":"Name29","username":"Username29","password":"password29","age":49,"sex":true},
                        {"id":30,"name":"Name30","username":"Username30","password":"password30","age":50,"sex":true}
                       ]
                     }
                    ]
                  } 

          document.write(obj.records[0].beans.Person[0].id);
     </script>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

But when I view this file in browser the displayed webpage is not showing **21**. I expect that page should display 21.

You can just copy and paste the source code and try it. It is not displaying **21**. How can i access these values.

Comment: Use `JSON.parse(jsonString)` to convert the json string to javascript object, and use index to iterate through the contents!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is the use of the `"."` in the identifier `"beans.Person"` meaning that you must quote it, like so:

```
obj.records[0]["beans.Person"][0].id
```

And avoid using `document.write` unless you have a good reason for it and know what your doing.

```
<div id="result"></div>

var obj = {
    "records": [{
        "beans.Person": [{
            "id": 21,
            "name": "Name21",
            "username": "Username21",
            "password": "password21",
            "age": 41,
            "sex": true
        }, {
            "id": 22,
            "name": "Name22",
            "username": "Username22",
            "password": "password22",
            "age": 42,
            "sex": true
        }, {
            "id": 23,
            "name": "Name23",
            "username": "Username23",
            "password": "password23",
            "age": 43,
            "sex": true
        }, {
            "id": 24,
            "name": "Name24",
            "username": "Username24",
            "password": "password24",
            "age": 44,
            "sex": true
        }, {
            "id": 25,
            "name": "Name25",
            "username": "Username25",
            "password": "password25",
            "age": 45,
            "sex": true
        }, {
            "id": 26,
            "name": "Name26",
            "username": "Username26",
            "password": "password26",
            "age": 46,
            "sex": true
        }, {
            "id": 27,
            "name": "Name27",
            "username": "Username27",
            "password": "password27",
            "age": 47,
            "sex": true
        }, {
            "id": 28,
            "name": "Name28",
            "username": "Username28",
            "password": "password28",
            "age": 48,
            "sex": true
        }, {
            "id": 29,
            "name": "Name29",
            "username": "Username29",
            "password": "password29",
            "age": 49,
            "sex": true
        }, {
            "id": 30,
            "name": "Name30",
            "username": "Username30",
            "password": "password30",
            "age": 50,
            "sex": true
        }]
    }]
}

document.getElementById("result").textContent = obj.records[0]["beans.Person"][0].id;
```

on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/faFGc/)

Answer (score 2):

Use `JSON.parse()` to get a javascript object from JSON string. You can get more information [here](http://www.json.org/js.html).

**EDIT:**

```
var objectID = obj.records[0]['beans.Person'][0]['id'];
```

A nice read, [Use Square Bracket Notation](http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/bestpractices/#squarebracket).

Comment: I am already using that already that above example is a sample I am interested in how to these data. Put simply I am asking for syntax for accessing id,username,password.

Answer (score 1):

try this, i'm sure it will work

```
document.write(obj.records[0]['beans.Person'][0]['id']);
```

check console, i'm petty sure you were having errors. It is taking beans and person two different objects

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample of your object in Back End Code C#

```
public Class Learner
{
     public string Name {get; set;}
     public string Surname {get; set;}
}
```

Then in JavaScript when reading the object from JsonResult

```
 var leanerName = obj[0].Name;
 var leanerSurname = obj[0].Surname;
```

Hope this helps